# What's the difference between state.sls and state.apply?

Tags: python, salt-stack

What's the difference between state.apply and state.sls? When should I use state.apply vs state.sls?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`state.sls <state_file>` will execute the states in a specific file.

`state.highstate` will execute the highstate configured by `top.sls`

`state.apply` will do a `state.highstate` if no arguments are given and a `state.sls <state_file>` when a  argument is given.

You can look at `state.apply` as an easy way of using states command.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: As `state.sls` takes at [least one argument](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.sls) is safer to use it.